# Does priority inheritance cure priority inversion?

Tags: rtos, freertos

In the Mutex description page of the FreeRTOS website the following sentence can be find:

> Priority inheritance does not cure priority inversion

From what I know I thought that priority inheritance was a cure for priority inversion. If the high priority task A is blocked by the low priority task B, with priority inheritance, task B inherits the priority level of task A (high). This means that no medium priority task can delay the execution of task A. As a consequence, priority inversion does not occur.
What is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is meant is that there are situations that can occur that are priority inversion and are not solved by priority inheritance.

An example:
The normal situation used is that task **A**, **B**, **C** are in decreasing priority.  **C** takes a mutex, then **B** becomes ready and is running.  Now **A** becomes ready.  **A** needs the mutex, so blocks on it.  Then **B** continues running which prevents **C** from releasing the mutex.  This effectively makes **B** have enough priority to block **A** from doing work.

The priority inheritance would make **C** have the same priority as **A**.  But consider the case where **C** cannot complete its work to release the mutex without **B** doing work.  Then because of the priority inheritance, you have a deadlock.

Therefore, priority inversion can exist, and it can be hard to detect potential failures.  The solution is to attempt to avoid it by design as much as possible.

Here's the entire blurb from the freertos site:

> Priority inheritance does not cure priority inversion! It just
>   minimises its effect in some situations. Hard real time applications
>   should be designed such that priority inversion does not happen in the
>   first place.

Answer (score 1):

If task C needs task B to complete a work so task C can relase the first mutex, then there must be a second lock/mutex connection between tasks C and B which priority inheritance could use to rise the priority of task B, allowing task B to finish the work needed by Task C so it can release the first mutex.